# Scraping <span> flow with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on scraping the data from a website using BeautifulSoup. I cannot seem to find a way to get the text between span elements to print. Below is the structure.

```
<span class="greyText smallText">
                avg rating 4.02 —
                132,623 ratings  —
                published 2014
              </span>
<span class="greyText smallText">
                avg rating 4.03 —
                82,319 ratings  —
                published 2015
              </span>
```

I need to find avg ratings and ratings in separate.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url= "https://someurl"
page = requests.get(url) 
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
ratings = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'greyText smallText'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution: you can use `re` module to extract the average ratings:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<span class="greyText smallText">
                avg rating 4.02 —
                132,623 ratings  —
                published 2014
              </span>
<span class="greyText smallText">
                avg rating 4.03 —
                82,319 ratings  —
                published 2015
              </span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for span in soup.select('span.greyText.smallText'):
    avg_rating = re.search(r'avg rating ([\d.]+)', span.text)
    if avg_rating:
        print(avg_rating[1])
```

Prints:

```
4.02
4.03
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its not working showing TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @Kashif Instead of `avg_rating[1]` use `avg_rating.group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [32]: [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all("span",class_="greyText smallText")]
Out[32]:
['avg rating 4.02 —\n                132,623 ratings  —\n                published 2014',
 'avg rating 4.03 —\n                82,319 ratings  —\n                published 2015']
```

Ratings as separate Value:

```
In [48]: [i.text.strip().split("\n")[0] for i in soup.find_all("span",class_="greyText smallText")]
Out[48]: ['avg rating 4.02 —', 'avg rating 4.03 —']
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, however how do I find only avg ratings in separate value

Comment: @Kashif Updated my answer